# Signed applet loads signed jar-files using URLClassLoader with security issue

Tags: java, security, applet, signed, urlclassloader

I have a signed applet. To implement some plugin architecture I download and store to disk a JAR file with specific classes.

Then I load these classes with `URLCLassLoader`. So, now I try to invoke some method from loaded class and I have a security issue.

It seems to "sign-token" cannot be checked by `SecurityManager` when class loaded be `URLClassLoaded`. Anybody know how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Loading.

```
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {libraryArchive.toURI().toURL()}, Compress.class.getClassLoader());
```

Invocation.

```
...
org.palettelabs.comm.desktopcapture.pim.Library lib = libraryClass.newInstance();
                final Compress compressingLibrary = (Compress) lib;
                File file = AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<File>() {

                    @Override
                    public File run() {
                        try {
                            File file = compressingLibrary.compress(filesList);
                            return file;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Logger.error("applet: compress: invocation external library error", e);
                            return null;
                        }
                    }

                });
```

Exception.

```
2011-09-16 16:00:08,550 [SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-4] ERROR - applet: compress: invocation external library error
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission /tmp/dca-palettelabs-storage/test/compress/linux32ffmpeg.jar-extractedFiles/org/palettelabs/
comm/desktopcapture/libs/compress/linux32 read)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:871)
        at java.io.File.exists(File.java:731)
        at java.io.File.mkdirs(File.java:1181)
        at org.palettelabs.comm.desktopcapture.pim.Library.extract(Library.java:31)
        at org.palettelabs.comm.desktopcapture.libs.compress.linux32.Linux32.compress(Linux32.java:17)
        at org.palettelabs.comm.desktopcapture.ui.UploadingWorker$1.run(UploadingWorker.java:77)
        at org.palettelabs.comm.desktopcapture.ui.UploadingWorker$1.run(UploadingWorker.java:1)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.palettelabs.comm.desktopcapture.ui.UploadingWorker.compress(UploadingWorker.java:72)
        at org.palettelabs.comm.desktopcapture.ui.UploadingWorker.doInBackground(UploadingWorker.java:57)
        at org.palettelabs.comm.desktopcapture.ui.UploadingWorker.doInBackground(UploadingWorker.java:1)
        at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:277)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Applet works fine without security manager when it runs from applet-launcher under eclipse.

Comment: Thanks! But explain me how it can be implemented? Browser uses special plugin which invokes JVM to run applet. How can I change default SecurityManager to mine?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works fine. I've extended `SecurityManager` class and  declared proper rules for validation of my classes. Please post your answer as answer for my question, I'd like to mark it as a best solution.

Comment: Done! Glad you got it sorted.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install a custom security manager that allows code from the right code base (package, whatever..) to perform that action.

To do that, call `System.setSecurityManager(myManager)`.  (As you managed to figure) `myManager` is an extension of [SecurityManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html).

It requires a trusted applet to set a security manager.

Comment: Set the `SecurityManager` in **an applet**??

Comment: @Tom I don't understand your question.

Comment: So if you set a security manager in an applet, it affects all applets from everywhere within the same process. You don't want to do that. (Also, you don't want two different applets doing that.)

Comment: Yes, you're right. But my own `SecurityManager` checks signature of loaded classes. So I can guarantee security of my "dynamic" code. What other applets can be loaded by this process? For each applet new instance of JVM will be created.

Comment: It has become more common for applets to have their own VM.  OTOH if you can launch your applet at your site in a separate VM, someone else can launch *your* applet at *their* site so it shares a VM with other applets, one of which might be the 'Trojan horse' that uploads the user's sensitive information and then wipes the disks.  You probably don't want your digital signature being the one that pops up for the user to approve in that circumstance.  Security is not trivial, the stakes are high and the bad guys very clever.

Answer (score 1):

Use an appropriate subclass of `java.security.SecureClassLoader` to assign an appropriate `ProtectionDomain` to the loaded classes. Of course, making sure that these classes are to be trusted by some mechanism (e.g. signed with a certificate you trust for such purposes).