# Java extensible applet

Tags: java, plugins, applet, extensible

I need to make an extensible applet that will have plugins downloaded from server and included dynamically in my applet.
I managed to do this locally without an applet, but when I try to port it to the applet I stumble across some problems

1. How can I sign my plugins so that it can access resources from client computer?
2. I have some external libraries thar are used in the applet and in the plugin, how do I manage those libraries so they can be visible to both applet and plugin?

**UPDATE** I managed to load the jars with a URLClassLoader that has the AppletClassLoader as parent so now the libraries mentioned at point 2 are visible to plugin and applet, the problem that remains is how can i sing my plugins(jars) so that they can access resources on client computer

Answer (score 1):

I hava managed to accomplish what i wanted by extending the SecurityManagaer according to this post: 
[Signed applet loads signed jar-files using URLClassLoader with security issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446009/signed-applet-loads-signed-jar-files-using-urlclassloader-with-security-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Java WebStart and jnlp client instead of applet?

For signing you have to use keytool and jarsigner command line utilities in JDK.

The "plugin" concept here not clear to me.

Comment: I have components packed as jars, the user starts the applet, downloads the component through the applet that he wants to use in the applet, the component is added dinamically to the applet as a new tab.I signed my applet, but how can i do it for the plugins considering that the plugins are put in a Plugins folder on server, are not mentioned in the HTML page of the applet and are downloaded and included dinamically. Thank you